# Boolean modifier hides linked object mesh

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view

I'm facing the following display "issue".

I'm on Blender 3.2, and I wanted to cut a hole trough a cube, so I created a cylinder, selected it, then selected the cube and created the boolean modifier.

[image: pre boolean]

The boolean modifier works, as I correctly see the hole, however the cylinder has now got a rectangular outline

[image: after boolean]

And even after deleting the boolean operator, I'm unable to see the original cylinder mesh (outline and material missing).

[image: boolean deleted]

On a tutorial I actually see the real cylindrical shape is maintained when creating the boolean operation, so I'm wondering what I'm missing? It looks like a display property, but can't really understand which one is giving me this issue!

[image: wanted]

Comment: Ha finaly, i was waiting for such feature , but right - it could be switched back when not used by any boolean  ... What you see Is Bonding box display type ... Go to Object Properties > Viewport Display and switch Textured.

Comment: Tutorial screen was probably switched into Wireframe display type manually.

Comment: @vklidu omg thanks! That was it! During boolean operations "Display As > Wire" is what I was looking for, and "Textured" for when I remove the modifier. Thank you!

Comment: @vklidu just for completeness, the Bool Tool addon has a "Display as wireframe" checkbox that automatically uses Wireframe display instead of bounding box for all boolean modifiers!

Comment: Hm ... I checked it and I see there is not a new feature in my 3.2 or 3.3 version. Manually added modifier keeps Textured display as before. And just when BoolTool addon is activated and I search for Boolean than btool Brush is only found. So switch to Bounding Box display is act of addon, not modifier's feature. BTW I also do not see option for btool to switch into wireframe.

Comment: @vklidu The option for the bool tool to switch into wireframe is in the addon's preferences. It's either On or Off so you can't select which modifier uses the option.